# Typescript generic and extend

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-generics, typescript1.5

I am new to Typescript.

I have following 4 interfaces :

```
export interface MyAction<T = any> {
  type: T
}

export interface MyAnyAction extends MyAction {
  [extraProps: string]: any
}

export interface MyAnyAnyAction extends MyAnyAction{

}

export interface ITestDispatch<A extends MyAction = MyAnyAction> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): T
}
```

I want to create a function of type "ITestDispatch".

I could not understand why TS compiler is throwing error for the below function :

```
const TestDispatch1Func: ITestDispatch1<MyAnyAction> = (action: MyAnyAnyAction): MyAnyAnyAction => {


  let obj: MyAnyAnyAction = { 
        type: 'skdw',
        da: 20
  };

  return obj;
}
```

I am getting the below error on "TestDispatch1Func" :

`Type '(action: MyAnyAnyAction) => MyAnyAnyAction' is not assignable to type 'ITestDispatch<MyAnyAction>'.   Type 'MyAnyAnyAction' is not assignable to type 'T'.     'MyAnyAnyAction' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'MyAnyAction'`.

Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: `<T extends A>(action: T): T` implies that your function has to return the same subtype of `A` that its argument has. So your function takes an argument `action` which could be a subtype of `MyAnyAction` and has to return the same subtype; but it actually just returns the base type, `MyAnyAction`.

Comment: @kaya3 I have modified my question. Would you please look at it and tell me whether my modified example satisfy the requirements according to your argument or not ? Thanks.

Comment: You can tell that it doesn't, because Typescript still gives you the type error. The function type `<T extends A>(action: T): T` is only satisfied by a function which returns the same type as its argument, which could be any subtype of `A`. Your modified function ignores the type of its argument `action` completely, and returns only one hard-coded subtype of `MyAnyAction`, so it does not guarantee to return the same subtype as `action` has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the interface `ITestDispatch` means that the function can take an action of any subtype of `A`, so it's conflicting with the types declaration & return type of the function `TestDispatch1Func` which is limited to `MyAnyAnyAction`. The interface is accepting any subtype of A, while the implementation is accepting only 1 subtype.

For instance if you had another interface

```js
export interface AnotherAction extends MyAnyAction{}
```

The definition `ITestDispatch1<MyAnyAction>` allows you to call `TestDispatch1Func(action: AnotherAction)` since `AnotherAction extends MyAnyAction`, but that would obviously conflict with the function defnition expecting only `MyAnyAnyAction`.

There are 3 solutions here

```js
export interface MyAction<T = any> {
  type: T
}

export interface MyAnyAction extends MyAction {
  [extraProps: string]: any
}

export interface MyAnyAnyAction extends MyAnyAction{}


// solution 1: specify the action input & output types in function defnition
export interface ITestDispatch1<T extends MyAction = MyAnyAction> {
  (action: T): T
}

// this means that the function will always be called with MyAnyAnyAction and return MyAnyAnyAction
const TestDispatchFunc1: ITestDispatch1<MyAnyAnyAction> = (action) => {
  // here you can always return `MyAnyAnyAction`,
  // because you explicitly declared it the as function output type
  let obj: MyAnyAnyAction = { 
        type: 'skdw',
        da: 20
  };

  return obj;
}


// solution 2: separate action input & output types, specify output type in function defintion
export interface ITestDispatch2<A extends MyAction, R extends A> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): R
}

// this function can be called with any subtype of MyAnyAction, but will always return MyAnyAnyAction
const TestDispatchFunc2: ITestDispatch2<MyAnyAction, MyAnyAnyAction> = (action) => {
  // here you can always return `MyAnyAnyAction`,
  // because you explicitly declared it the as function output type
  let obj: MyAnyAnyAction = { 
        type: 'skdw',
        da: 20
  };

  return action;
}


// solution 3: decide the function input & output types types in function invocation
export interface ITestDispatch3<A extends MyAction = MyAnyAction> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): T
}

// this function can be called with any subtype of MyAnyAction, returns the same subtype
const TestDispatchFunc3: ITestDispatch3<MyAnyAction> = (action) => {
  // can't return MyAnyAnyAction because the return type is the same as the input type,
  // which can be any subtype of MyAnyAction, not necessarily MyAnyAnyAction
  // let obj: MyAnyAnyAction = { 
  //       type: 'skdw',
  //       da: 30
  // };

  return action;
}

// the result type is determined base on the input type
const result1 = TestDispatchFunc3({} as MyAnyAnyAction) // result: MyAnyAnyAction
const result2 = TestDispatchFunc3({} as MyAnyAction) // result: MyAnyAction
```

[TS Playground here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=69&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8BBbGBCJAHgBU4BeOTJQgPjgG8AoOOGQsMABccGlwC%20XLqEixEKNFlwESLUuUpxQqJABMAzivUUknHnADa2qJgAKUCGH0j9MKMgDmAXRHNCEqRloeGRUDBw8ImI1NTITLRAdAyNYjSQOSSkAeiy4fQgAGwBXNLgARhdBbAR0Qj4ACzwcUuQwErgAMjgIErb4fkFDZDh0IqQ4zV1gdCQENOlwYPkwpTwASRpgVwARBH0wTBhserLaBKTDKInTRijUk3ZuXgAKZpMRGgBKD4CuHIa9nAALbAZiGGD1Q4NPCjcalADuCAKBSYBXhmEIhgARnhsJhkcBdHBERCUqoSNcmHo4FBgDAilBTHdycZKFxsJRXKItjBdvtDscAGJjbAVOAbHl8g5HE5UZnRClpdiMV7XT4MR7mf6NWlwQg9OB40z49GYml0hmmAAG8vulCtABotbkcXiivo8PqigkwAUENUYAU6lNsAVMLSiXNoUxDLDKT0YH0%20AJgOYCnTuliAFYiW2K%20KMDhwcy8UvJwQiADk%20gA1rp4ZWnWWy7pMCIAEwABnM4gA3FJeLT6YzM1n%205k-rl8sVSu2XMADjZUExKa12l0E0mBlsHXkqjU6pv2tv5CMRaUpuhQiYFrIQgpwsoJTs9tLju2qMRzsA9Jd85RdwAJW-X84GITVeDObQf2ScDVTSD5vjgQDfn%20CFATjUojTgHFDXxdMiRJeoqTqfQiixE8IHQMlWSQXcsXaRFkVRU1DCHS0aLtJB2U5eBNhffkZWFcY53FfjeVfAV6g-eVrl3PNaOVOB4JMdV6AguBtTQT0DWwk0MTYi0RxtFkuMdZ0cOAN0PT1A0ZD9AMgzgEMwwjRB%20kaGMzzheIj36FM0wzCBs1zUz-xuThi2bUttyrWt60bEtm1bDtu14PsB3NYdjWuccpEnPJChKeIAGYRBDBApmjTD4jXeAN16Y8U3BZrTxqzRkAANwgPF5iCORQkUCIxMlSSZRKz8QOSK5SluFlrg0qDEhgww4LeShEJ%20TI0PqDDz3ibDcLxAlCLmYi-DycjKOo2S0l3djGXBTz9EwEFLoogKOSQLlxKlKThOwMqRoEt96gm26HgYZT1qQNSNP%20I1K3gB6mTC2jLOsvAITwFHyzwQFsbyV6mie-GkC3FMm003J4V2448NMXCLrIj7BG6G75ruuAkAgeAkCsrYXvcJyFOuCz03gYKc048KoaLCzotiuBqzrBsqf%20aKUrgEq0upuAMvMXGYbygrCdpMiCn8tnASmMIgWQQkcMwGzNEJuq8Z477ka2IpLbKKHfrGoURRK54Mi80W0nVf5zd9mBQoVROxa%20rlY8t9sA9GwTg-GUPw%20dmi1T1tP48L%20YuCAA)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually an obscure mistake in your function signature. `<MyAnyAction>` declares a new Type Parameter that changes the meaning of MyAnyAction. It is difficult to spot because the Type Parameter has the same name as an interface in your code.

```
const TestDispatch1Func: ITestDispatch<MyAnyAction> =
    <MyAnyAction>(action: MyAnyAction): MyAnyAction => {
```

It should be

```
const TestDispatch1Func: ITestDispatch<MyAnyAction> =
    (action: MyAnyAction): MyAnyAction => {
```

For a bit more context you can rename `<MyAnyAction>` to anything, since it's a type parameter and in this context it means create a Type Parameter called MyAnyAction. If you rename is then the error is also clearer:

```
const TestDispatch1Func: ITestDispatch<MyAnyAction> = <T>(action: T): T => {
```

> Type 'MyAnyAction' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'MyAnyAction' is
>   assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be
>   instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'

Comment: Thanks. But, if I use the above construct, then I am getting the below error : Type '(action: MyAnyAction) => MyAnyAction' is not assignable to type 'ITestDispatch1<MyAnyAction>'.   Type 'MyAnyAction' is not assignable to type 'T'.     'MyAnyAction' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'MyAnyAction'

Comment: @sudip I think the question is why do you want `ITestDispatch` to be a generic function in `T`. If you really want to make it generic this will work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8BBbGBCJAHgBU4BeOTJQgPjgG8AoOOGQsMABccGlwC+XLqEixEKNFlwESLUuUpxQqJABMAzivUUknHnADa2qJgAKUCGH0j9MKMgDmAXRHNCEqRloeGRUDBw8ImI1NTITLRAdAyNYjSRuAOlwYPkwpTwASRpgVwARBH0wTBhsAAsqYgSkwyi4zUYo1JN2bl5aJuA9Q2JWAAocNJEaAEopzK5sSldREphyyuq6gEYAMQBXJGwRItX1qpr6zpI2pHZGfu1B5Kvo67SxiZMp2dEGHvNeFBgDA9lBTJ9KBIgA . But the you can't create object literals of type `T` since `T` can be anythin

Comment: @sudip The point of the above construct was that you will get an error, but the message will show the MyAnyAction in your context was a type parameter.